# What are my options for interfacing **30** incremental encoders to an MCU?

Tags: microcontroller, fpga, interface, encoder

**Background:** I am familiar with interfacing *a few* incremental/quadrature encoders to a single MCU chip. My go-to chip `STM32F10x` can decode 4-5 encoders even in a LQFP64 package (e.g. `STM32F100R8T6` has 4), which had always been more than enough for me... *until now*.

**Problem:** I want an `ATXMEGA128` to effectively poll counts of all 30 encoders at 1kHz (say, by keeping 16-bit counters). I cannot change the `ATXMEGA128` to some other MCU, but I can add another MCU to interface with it.

The bottom line is I could slap on a FPGA (e.g. Spartan3E) and make it talk to MCU through SPI or parallel, but I'd like to consider some alternatives before I go down this path (for non-technical reasons). The number can be reduced to 15 if 30 seems too hard without FPGA.

Comment: I can't see any better way than using an FPGA if you need the parallelism. If you can read them (pseudo-)serially you might be able to divide them into groups and feed them into analog MUXes... but I imagine that would be unnecessarily bulky, expensive, and painful to route

Comment: @Shamtam MUX is another thing I'm trying to avoid here, due to complexity as you said.

Comment: You could group them and use smaller MCUs or maybe CPLDs for each group, in a modular fashion .

Comment: @SpehroPefhany CPLD might make sense as they're dead simple. Thanks for suggesting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the decision was to group them by 4 as @spehro-pefhany suggested in comment, and connect them to a bunch of MCUs, which can then communicate on SPI bus.

The main advantage is less cable mess, as I can place the MCUs close to the encoders.

Answer (score 1):

A small FPGA is the way to go here.  You would need a very large CPLD to manage this many encoders - they are not useful for much more than glue logic.  Generally a CPLD gives you one flip-flop per pin.  An FPGA has logic resources that are specifically designed for building things like accumulators and shift registers, and far more of them than a CPLD with the same number of pins.  For 30 encoders with 16 bit counters on each, that's a minimum of 480 flip flops just for the counters, not counting the encoder processing and SPI interface.  I would suggest a small Spartan 3 or Spartan 6 - they are available in TQFP and should be easy to interface with.

Comment: Spartans are definitely up to the job; I'm just wondering if I have alternatives...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use quadrature decoder chips? The [LSI LS7366R](http://www.lsicsi.com/pdfs/Data_Sheets/LS7366R.pdf) is a 32 bit quadrature decoder that also supports the index signal if needed. Everything you need is inside that chip and read via SPI.

There is also the old standard Avago, previously Agilent, previously HP [HCTL-2032-SC](http://www.avagotech.com/pages/en/motion_control_encoder_products/integrated_circuits/decoder_ic/hctl-2032-sc/). It uses an old school parallel bus interface and is in a large PDIP package. I am putting it here for reference as I have seen it used in many old CNC controllers.

Comment: This seems like a good idea. One problem is that if you put them all on the same SPI interface, you would need 30 enable or chip select signals. Maybe an IO expander for that part of the problem.

Comment: @mkeith : Sure I could use some address decoder, but still that means I need to put 30 of these on my board (lots of $).

To OP : Do you know anyone who sell them? Not mouser or digikey... I doubt if the price * 30 would beat a CPLD though.

Comment: US Digital sells them @4.75 each for quantities between 10 and 29 pieces: (http://www.usdigital.com/products/interfaces/ics/lfls7366r-s)

Comment: And as for cost, what is worth more: your time or a hundred fifty bucks in chips? Don't sell yourself short. Time is money. Even if it is a hobby project.

Comment: @mkeith - The demuxing is a no brainier using 5 bits of GPIO and two 74HC154's. No serial buses needed.

Comment: I have worked on projects where there were not 5 bits of IO available. But yeah, that would work, if there are.

Comment: I would be pretty hesitant to pay 4.75 for these things. That has to be some kind of joke.

Comment: I'd be hesitant to base anything other than a one-off on a chip without a major distributor.

Comment: I agree that this is a valid hardware-only solution (+), although at $4.75/ch this gets more expensive than FPGA both in cost and in time (-, need to route all 30 channels!)

Answer (score 0):

This solution is very extensible, but it creates a big mess of wires.

You can interface one encoder with two `74HC193`s and use a bunch of I2C GPIO extender to read them. This will allow you to add as many encoders as you like.

Comment: I'm afraid anything based upon I2C wouldn't be fast enough to keep up with the data rate...